# Do I need to pre-load my blow-up images in a jQuery slideshow, and, if so, how can I grab them in an array for pre-loading

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

My slideshow looks like this: https://img.skitch.com/20110727-gea94py8hbfse2fxhmbg3k7crc.jpg

So my challenge is figuring out how to pre-load the blow-up or "main" image when it doesn't exist on the page. I'm doing some URL trickery to get the path of the main image which uses a different Drupal image style (image cache preset), and therefore exists in a different folder with the same file name.

```
    //When a user clicks on a thumbnail this script will change the src of a target image
    //Declare the image style we'll be using for the large image.
    var imageStyle = 'slide_large';

    //Preload the large images 
    //Takes an array of images
    /*
    (function($) {
      var cache = [];
      // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
      $.preLoadImages = function() {
        var args_len = arguments.length;
        for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
          var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
          cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
          cache.push(cacheImage);
        }
      }
    })(jQuery)
    */

    //We'll need a function to grab the image name out of the image path
    function getImageName(mySRC) {
      var index = mySRC.lastIndexOf("/");
      var fileName = mySRC.substr(index+1);
      return fileName;
    };

    //Would be nice to grab the first thumbnail in the slider and make this the first image.


    //We'll want to swap out the main image when a user clicks on a thumb from the slider with the desired image.
    (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //$.preLoadImages("/path/to/image1.gif", "/path/to/image2.png");
        $(".jcarousel .field-content img").bind("click", function(){

            var imageName = getImageName(this.src);
            var imagePath = '/sites/default/files/styles/' + imageStyle + '/public/slides/' + imageName;

            $("#block-block-2 img").attr('src', imagePath);   
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

This is probably a simple matter of loading both the thumbs and main images into arrays, and submitting them into the preload function I found on Stack Overflow. So...

1. Do I need to preload?
2. How do I get everything into an array to submit to my preload function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pre-loading, which seems complicated since it will require putting all those blown-up images in a hidden div. I went to http://www.ajaxload.info/ and downloaded a throbber which I'll use as a background image for the main image slot, so if there is a delay loading an image it will make sense to the user.